# How can I do a zoom in animation transition with a circle and black background, fragment to activity? Zooming out once you have entered the activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-transitions

I'd like to have a button where if you click on it, it zooms in to the button and a black background engrosses your view, with a circle in the center that you can see through, then zooming out with the opposite effect.

Is something like this possible? If not please let me know about other similar animations I can pull off.

Like in the super mario games, when you enter a world.